# Using jQuery UI on page elements

Tags: jquery-ui, css

Is it possible to use the jQuery UI library to apply rounded corners to an element on the page? For example, I've applied some CSS to LI tags so that they look more like buttons and float next to each other. Nothing happens when I apply the following classes to the LI: `ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all`.

Is it that the styles only apply to jQuery UI elements? Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you have loaded the jQuery UI theme CSS file of your choice.  You might want to check that its a full theme and doesn't need the base theme loaded first.  Check with Firebug to see what style rules are being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can apply directly the round corners to your element. You don't need to use jquery ui for that.

```
$("#elementYouWant").css({
 "-moz-border-radius": "5px"
 "-webkit-border-radius": "5px",
 "-border-radius": "5px"
});
```